# Facebook Product Feed with user-generated products

Tags: facebook, pixel, facebook-pixel

Our customers can create a fully personalized products on our webshop. Facebook syncs these personalized products every hour by pinging our API.

When a customer creates its product, we trigger a ViewContent event with the product ID in our database. Since this does not yet exist in the Facebook catalog, the Facebook Pixel Helper shows a notice that the product cannot be matched to the catalog.

When Facebook syncs our database into the catalog, that product will be available, but the ViewContent events that happened in the past keep showing the issue that it cannot be matched to the catalog. Is our assumption correct that the ViewContent events **do not** retroactively get matched to the product in the catalog when it syncs?

This image illustrates our timeline:
[image: Timeline of pixel events]

Is there a way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to fully get your use case. But you can circumvent this by using offline conversions API of FB if you really need to fire a ViewContent after you customer creates a product on you web-shop:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions/

Why do you need to fire a ViewContent when the product is created? You can leverage pixel generated catalog in some circumstances, check the docs here:
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/887775018036966?id=725943027795860

When you fire pixel ViewContent event it will always go towards the FB user observing your web site at the moment. It doesn't make much sense to fire it at the moment of product creation.

By FB grabbing products against your API, do you mean that you expose a product catalog with a schedule to update it every hour?

Comment: We fire the ViewContent event after creation, because we want to remarket the user-generated product to said user. We create a customer segment that looks like:
Users that VIEWED product X and DID NOT PURCHASE after 2 hours

Pixel-generated catalogs are also not possible in our use case, since there is a delay of up to 15 minutes between firing & processing the product in the catalog.

Facebook is indeed scheduled to update the catalog every hour.

Would you have any other suggestions for the use case of remarketing a customer that created its fully customized product?

Comment: I understood the question better now. I worked in a couple of projects with similar requirements. Unfortunately, there is no simple solution. As a workaround you can:

1. Collect stats on the generated products and pre-generate the most popular combination. Then do mapping based on significant items the customer chosen in his customized product.

2. If you can identify the customer, just use off-line conversions or FB S2S API, but for the latter, you have to be whitelisted.

Comment: 3. Forget it and do generic retargeting as it's hard to prove that retarget with the customized item would yield significantly more conversions. Instead, you can have a message reminding of recent configuration the user has done and getting them back to refine and buy:))))

It very much depends on the product type of-course, the approach would be different for shoes, cars, insurances, utility contracts or it-services. Whatever it is)